# How can I modify library versions in the docker image used by dask workers?

Tags: dockerfile, dask, dask-distributed

I am trying to run a distributed computation using Dask on a AWS Fargate cluster (using `dask.cloudprovider` API) and I am running into the exact same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66388888/dask-cluster-attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-data). Based on the partial answers to the linked question, and on things like [this](http://5.9.10.113/65474079/attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-data), I heavily suspect it is due to the pandas version in my worker being outdated; and indeed the
[official Dask Dockerfile](https://github.com/dask/dask-docker/blob/main/base/Dockerfile) specifies a old-ish version of pandas.

By contrast, when I run my computation locally (using a `distributed.LocalCluster`) with a pandas version at `1.2.2` it works fine. Btw, it is a call to the `categorize` method on a Dask DataFrame that triggers the error in the Fargate cluster case.

What I would like to do as a workaround is simply to specify myself the version of pandas in the image deployed to the workers, either building a custom image myself + putting it on an image repo + have the worker use it, or through some other method. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option that might work is to pass environment variables, such as `EXTRA_CONDA_PACKAGES` and `EXTRA_PIP_PACKAGES`, to indicate the package versions you would like to install, which it looks like should be supported by `dask.cloudprovider` as seen [here](https://github.com/dask/dask-cloudprovider/blob/6a629089b583469f70879943d7f127b77c315736/dask_cloudprovider/aws/ecs.py#L580-L584), and also noted in the `dask-docker` [repo](https://github.com/dask/dask-docker#environment-variables) you linked.  They would be passed as a dict via a parameter `environment`.

Another option would be to build and push your own image as you mentioned, which also appears to be supported by `dask.cloudprovider` as indicated [here](https://github.com/dask/dask-cloudprovider/blob/6a629089b583469f70879943d7f127b77c315736/dask_cloudprovider/aws/ecs.py#L454-L457).  The image tag would be passed to the cluster constructor via the `image` parameter.

The options linked are for `ECSCluster`, which `FargateCluster` inherits from, as seen [here](https://github.com/dask/dask-cloudprovider/blob/6a629089b583469f70879943d7f127b77c315736/dask_cloudprovider/aws/ecs.py#L1240).